# Altering the Derby Metastore in Hive to allow for Structs with >4000B definitions

Tags: json, hadoop, amazon-web-services, hive, derby

We are creating an Hive schema for reading massive JSON files. Our JSON schema is rather large, and we have found that the default metastore schema for Hive cannot work for us as-is.

To be specific, one field in our schema has about 17KiB of nested structs within it. Unfortunately, it appears that Hive has a limit of `varchar(4000)` for the field that stores the resulting definition (looking at the Derby schema def ~v0.10 here):

```
CREATE TABLE "COLUMNS_V2" (
"CD_ID" bigint NOT NULL,
"COMMENT" varchar(4000),
"COLUMN_NAME" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
"TYPE_NAME" varchar(4000),
"INTEGER_IDX" INTEGER NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("CD_ID", "COLUMN_NAME")
);
```

We are running this on Amazon EC2/MapReduce (v0.11 with default Derby metastore)

So, our initial questions are: 
•   Is there a reason that the TYPE_NAME is being limited to 4000 (IIUC, `varchar` on Derby can grow to 32672, which would be sufficient for a long time)
•   Can we alter the `metastore` schema without hacking/reinstalling Hive (which would complicate automation w/AWS)? 
•   If so, is there a proper/preferred way to update the schema on all nodes?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can change the datatype of TYPE_NAME.If you have multinode cluster I will recommend you to use MySQL as hive metastore.More information related canbe found [here](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/4.2.0/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_18_4.html)